# Help on parsing formatted string

Tags: php, regex, string-parsing

I have strings:

```
17s 283ms
48s 968ms
```

The string values are never the same and I want to extract the "second" value from it.  In this case, the 17 and the 48.

I'm not very good with regex, so the workaround I did was this:

```
$str = "17s 283ms";    
$split_str = explode(' ', $str);

foreach($split_str as $val){
    if(strpos($val, 's') !== false) $sec = intval($val);
}
```

The problem is, the character **'s'** exists in both split_str[0] and split_str[1], so my $sec variable keeps obtaining 283, instead of 17.

Again, I'm not very good with regex, and I'm pretty sure regex is the way to go in this case.  Please assist.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this like so:

```
preg_match('/(?<seconds>\d+)s\s*(?<milliseconds>\d+)ms/', $var, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: I disagree with Jon. regex is NOT overkill and is perfectly appropriate for solving this problem. Crozin's solution here not only correctly extracts the seconds value (_and the milliseconds value_), it validates the input string as well. (Although I would add `^` and `$` anchors.) +1

Comment: +1 for this.  Sorry I didn't see it earlier.  Not only does it give the values, but adds flexibility because sometimes, the string values are something like 45mn 5s or 1h 22m.  I can also use this solution to return hours and minutes as well.

Answer (score 6):

You don't even need to use regex for this.

```
$seconds = substr($str, 0, strspn($str, '1234567890'));
```

The above solution will extract all the digits from the beginning of the string. Doesn't matter if the first non-digit character is "s", a space, or anything else.

### But why bother?

You can even just cast `$str` to an `int`:

```
$seconds = (int)$str; // equivalent: intval($str)
```

[See it in action](http://ideone.com/wiM0q).

Regular expressions are definite overkill for such a simple task. Don't use dynamite to drill holes in the wall.

Comment: +1 Nice solution. (Must confess `strspn` is a new one on me.)

Comment: Damn, that's a nice solution. I'm beaten.

Comment: wow i feel like an idiot.  i didn't know casting it as an int outputted that.  and great solution on the strspn.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with the "dynamite" remark. This is a _perfect_ example of a problem that is easily and accurately solved using regex (which is not overkill). A correct regex will not only extract the desired value(s) but will _validate the input_ as well. See Crozin's solution below.

Comment: @ridgerunner: Point taken. I answered in this manner not because the fact that it's more efficient *matters* (we should all know better than to optimize prematurely), but because we as developers should always apply practical reasoning and strive to use the correct tool for the job. In this case, I imagine that the OP heard "string parsing is done with regexes" somewhere and went off on that tangent. It may well be that in the context of a complete app the input has to be validated as well; but we don't know. So I went for a *practical* answer to what we do know.

Answer (score 1):

If the string will always be formatted in this manner, you could simply use:

```
<?php
    $timeString = '17s 283ms';
    $seconds = substr($timeString, 0, strpos($timeString, 's')); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i guess that you can assume seconds always comes before milliseconds. No need for regexp if the format is consistent. This should do it:

```
$parts = explode(' ', $str);
$seconds = rtrim($parts[0], 's')
echo $seconds; // 17s
```

This will split the string by space and take the first part `17s`. rtrim is then used to remove 's' and you're left with `17`.

Answer (score 0):

(\d+s) \d+ms

is the right regexp. Usage would be something like this:

```
$str = "17s 283ms";
$groups = array();
preg_match("/(\d+)s \d+ms/", $str, $groups);
```

Then, your number before ms would be `$groups[1]`.